# Aplicação C# com erro de conexão com Firebird no Windows 7 32/64 bits com 2GB de RAM

Tags: c#, firebird

Olá! estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C#, no qual eu já a instalei em varias máquinas para teste com o windows xp, 7 e 8 e em todos eles a aplicação funcionou corretamente, porém em uma máquina especifica ele simplesmente não roda e mostra a seguinte mensagem na execução da aplicação!

[image: Mensagem de Erro]

Agora tem o seguinte detalhe essa máquina já foi formatada e assim mesmo o problema persiste, sendo se eu apontar o banco dela para outra máquina ela roda normalmente sem nenhum problema já quando o banco está local ela gera esse erro, sendo que também tenho outros programas usando firebird sem problemas algum, o firebird instalado é idêntico ao qual o projeto foi criado. Realmente eu não sei mas o que fazer!

Comment: Mesma versão do Firebird em todas as máquinas? Que driver você usa pra acessar o banco? Este driver também é da mesma versão que as demais?

Comment: Sim, tanto o firebird como o driver estão todos na mesma versão!

Comment: Qual é o driver?

Comment: É que tem um detalhe, eu uso uma outra IDE para o desenvolvimento, no qual ela já me fornece essa conexão. Sendo que eu nunca tive qualquer problema, sendo que nessa mesma máquina que estava com o xp estava funcionando, mas devido a outras aplicações foi formatada para o 7, depois disso começou a ocorre os problemas!

Comment: Se você não sabe qual é o driver, você não tem como saber que todas as máquinas estão com a mesma versão, certo? Creio que você precisará compreender como se dá esta conexão, que driver ou biblioteca é utilizado. Com o novo Windows uma outra versão com outros requisitos pode estar em uso, não apenas de driver do lado do cliente mas possivelmente algum recurso do próprio Firebird. Possivelmente você encontrará um meio de fazer a conexão de modo que funcione com qualquer versão.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema fazendo a atualização da UDF ao qual o Firebird chamava!